# Anyone have trouble with sharp turns on the townie?

Tags: commuter

Anyone have trouble with sharp turns on the townie? Twice I’ve lost control when making a sharp turn. The bike seems to just collapse, or pull out from under me. The others I ride with don’t seem to have this problem, but they don’t have townies.

Comment: Can you show a clear picture of your bike from the side? Incorrect assembly of the forks could cause something like this.

Comment: I presume your bike looks something like any of these:   https://www.google.com/search?q=townie+bike&tbm=isch      Is that about right ?

Comment: Do you have access to a tyre pressure gauge, or a pump with a gauge ?  Curious to know what air pressure is inside your tyres now.

Comment: Winter riding is different : Watch out for wet leaves, sand/gravel, white lines or crossings, cast iron drains, the sheen of oil, any moisture right after a dry spell, and of course ice or snow. Learn the bike : recovering from a rear wheel slip may be much easier than losing the front wheel; if so avoid the front brake in the wet where you can.

Answer (score 12):

cmaster already mentioned the most important points. A few other factors:

- Tyre pressure. Especially on loose or rough ground it can make a big difference.
- Braking. Avoid braking *in* turns, brake before turns. You have a total “budget” of friction which has to cover both braking and turning (centripetal) forces. Same applies to acceleration.
- Distribution of weight. If your front wheel loses grip much earlier and unexpectedly it could be because you have too much weight on your rear wheel. Usually you should lose grip on the rear wheel first which is much more controllable. Edit: Looking at photos of the Electra Townie this could indeed be a major culprit and inherent problem of the frame geometry. Most of the rider’s weight is on the back wheel. This is especially problematic when combined with (strong) front braking.
- Suspension.
- Pedal strike. Make sure your inside pedal doesn’t hit the ground in sharp turns. Keep the outside pedal down and the inside pedal up. Don’t pedal.
- Make sure your bike works correctly and reliably: Handlebars turn smoothly and without play in the headset bearing, handlebars and stem are symmetric and aligned with the front wheel, wheels are seated properly in the dropouts and don’t have any play, brakes work smoothly and without shudder …

Answer (score 6):

When your bike suddenly disappears beneath you in a curve, that invariably means that you lost traction. I.e. that the sideways force at the contact with the road exceeded the physical limits.

Now, traction (the amount of lateral force that can be transmitted through the road contact, or equivalently the lean angle at which you loose traction) is controlled by two factors, only:

1. Tire material. Some rubber mixes are simply better than others. Tires can also age and lose grip, but that's generally not a very pronounced effect. Nevertheless, tires that develop cracks in their flanks need to be replaced.
2. Road conditions. Water, sand and other debris significantly reduce traction, not to mention ice and snow. However, that's not the full story, the road itself can be in bad conditions. Stuff like tree roots, potholes, uneven stones, slick stones, tar lines (where cracks have been patched up), too smooth surface, etc. can all reduce traction, and thus push you over the limit when your lean angle is too flat.

I would check your tire brand first. What tires do your friends ride, and what type do you use. If it's no-name tires, then they are likely the culprit.

If your tires are known to be good (= same type as your friends), you probably need to pay closer attention to the ground while cornering, and/or try to steer a smoother line through the curve. Your aim is to reduce the maximal lean angle, to avoid bad contact spots where possible, and to reduce your lean angle prior to passing over bad spots you can't avoid.

Comment: Tyres: It's usually not a matter of "better" but *more suitable*  Marathon Plus, for example (a popular commuter tyre), use a compound that's great for lasting a long time and not getting puncture, but it's not great for cornering like you're in a race, especially on wet roads.  Other tyres from the same brand perform differently (Marathon *Supreme* are a puncture-protected fast touring tyre and have more grip on roads but wear faster).  Truly dreadful tyres exist but even the stock ones on cheap bike struggle more with punctures, wear,  and comfort than grip

Comment: I'd avoid using 'brand' as a differentiator for rubber mixes.  Just as an example, theres a whole world of difference between continentals black chilli compound and their lowest tier compound.

Comment: @AndyP Yeah, the word "brand" was probably too general. What I meant to say was the fully specified tire, such that two tires of the same "brand" would have equal rubber, structure, etc, just not necessarily the same size. I don't know what a good term for that would be. Anyway, I've removed the word brand now, as I'm only really concerned about the rubber mixture here.

Comment: @AndyP I've now settled on using "type" instead of "brand", I hope that conveys my meaning sufficiently. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are following very basic techniques, this should not happen. You are either trying something contra-intuitive or there are problems with your bicycle.

- You may be trying some technique that was wrongly described where you read about it or wrongly understood (like "counter steering"). Try simpler. You should both steer and lean in the direction you are turning, and "do not brake in turns" just means brake before.
- There is just a limit how fast you can turn, try slower. Advanced techniques may allow faster turns but before mastering them you can always just slow down instead.
- The ground matters, respect things like pebbles on the road.

Apart that, it may be problems with the frame, but likely not with the model or townies in general but with your particular bicycle. Post the photo of it so that the community could check.

While tires generally matter, basic turn at slow speed should be easy with any tires, regardless how much are they inflated. Also, I cannot really believe you strike a pedal into ground while turning without understanding, what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does a very poor job at describing the problem you're experiencing, so is can't be answered without a lot of guesswork. The other answers are assuming that the problem is grip-related. Losing grip is certainly a common cause for loss of control, specifically, when you lose grip in a corner you will always fall *inwards* (e.g. right turn → wheel slips out to the left → you fall to the right).

But to me, “just collapse, or pull out from under me” sounds rather like the *opposite* is happening: you steer right, the bike pulls *too strongly* to the right and you fall to the left? (Again, this is pretty much guesswork.)

In that case, grip is certainly not the issue. But I could well see this phenomenon happening specifically with the Electra Townie. That bike has a... *questionable* geometry if you ask me, namely very slack head- and seat angles, *not* a long wheelbase, but long chainstays.

A slack fork has stability advantages at high speed and for steep descents, which is clearly not what this bike is designed for. At low speed,  it's rather the opposite: the slack front makes the steering more and more floppy the stronger you turn. It may be particularly dangerous because at speed, the [trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry#Trail) keeps the steering centered to you get used to making rather strong steering inputs to get the bike to turn at all, but then when you slow down for a sharp turn the slack angle causes the opposite effect: the steering flops *outwards*, so it's easy to accidentally steer to much.

The long chainstays (i.e. the pedals are not near the rear wheel, but rather far to the front) don't help either. A consequence of this and the short wheelbase is that you get substantial [toe overlap](https://www.rivbike.com/pages/toe-overlap). That can be a mild nuisance in normal road riding, but specifically in a strong turn it can mean your foot actually locks the wheel in to the turned position. Then you can't get the steering back, which may be needed for keeping the balance. Watch out for this – check how close your feet get to the front wheel at different pedal- and steering positions. In doubt, it's a good idea to keep the curve-inner pedal up and outer pedal down while going through a corner (i.e. in a right turn, the right pedal should be in 12 o'clock position, the left pedal in 6 o'clock position). This way you preclude strikes with both the ground and the front wheel, even on a bike with bad geometry.

Regardless of what the actual problem is – the best solution is to *practice more*, deliberately get the bike to its limits, predict when you're starting to fall, and get the reflexes up so you can just catch it with a quick foot dab on the ground instead of crashing.

But yes, the Townie is probably part of the reason why this happens to you. I wouldn't recommend anybody to choose that bike or similar ones – but tastes vary of course.

Comment: To me, OP’s issue sounds like the same geometry issues that early 29ers had where slow, tight steering with the bars at a high angle wasn’t very stable and caused the bike to jack knife without a considerable amount of skill.